# C# Math.Round Issue

Tags: c#, rounding

I am having trouble rounding a number in C#.  Here is my code:

```
public static double GetHighTargetHR (string birthdate, string examDate)
{
  double HighTargetHR = 0;
  double age;
  double constant = 220;

  age = CalculateAge(birthdate, examDate);

  if (age > 0)
  {
    HighTargetHR = ((constant - age) * 0.8);
    Math.Round(HighTargetHR, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
  }

  return HighTargetHR;
}
```

This patient's age is 26.  So 220-26 = 194 * 0.8 = 155.20

I want the code to return 155.  No matter what I change on the Math.Round function, it returns 155.20.  How can I make it return an even number?

Comment: `Math.Round()` returns the rounded value. You're ignoring the return value.

Comment: As Pac0 and CodeCaster mentioned, you're not returning the result of your rounding call, you're just throwing it away.

Comment: `Int`s are value types. They are not passed by reference (like reference types) into methods so cannot be manipulated. Hence the method returns a value. See [What is the difference between a reference type and value type in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057267/what-is-the-difference-between-a-reference-type-and-value-type-in-c)

Comment: @Liam Reference types or value types are not passed by reference unless `ref` our `out` is specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to affect the result of Math.Round to the variable. Otherwise, it is simply discarded.

```
 HighTargetHR = Math.Round(HighTargetHR, ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the result of the function you are using (`Math.Round`):

```
HighTargetHR = Math.Round((constant - age) * 0.8, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

A function returns a value; so, when you use some function, you have to assign its returned value to a variable.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing to use the return type of round function.

```
HighTargetHR = Math.Round(HighTargetHR, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```